# Shared access signature support with Azure Service Bus trigger input/output for Azure Functions 2

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

Azure Service Bus trigger is used for Azure Functions for Topic and subscription, I wonder if Azure Service Bus trigger input and output support shared access signature (SAS)?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-sas
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus

**Output**

```
  [FunctionName(nameof(Order))]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Order(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)]
            HttpRequest request,
            [ServiceBus("%TopicName%", EntityType.Topic, Connection = "AzureServiceBus_ConnectionString")]
            IAsyncCollector<Message> collector)  
        {

                await collector.AddAsync(message);

        }
```

**Inupt**

```
[FunctionName("ServiceBusQueueTriggerCSharp")]                    
public static void Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] 
    string myQueueItem,
    Int32 deliveryCount,
    DateTime enqueuedTimeUtc,
    string messageId,
    ILogger log)
{
```

}

Any idea?

If not supported, any workaround

Comment: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/31839700-support-service-bus-trigger-with-use-of-sas-token

Comment: oh, no!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Page not found... so supported or not?